# Run PHP submit code prior to HTML form action to set SESSION variables

Tags: php, html

Is there a way when a user submits an HTML form to run the PHP code necessary to save the form data as session variables prior to executing the HTML form's action and leaving the page?  When I set the form action to go to the next page (session2.php) it does so without running the PHP associated with the submit button.  If I remove the form action then I need JavaScript in the PHP submit script to bring the user to the next page.

Is there a way to run the PHP and then the run the form action, or is it best to leave as-is?  I do have **session_start();** as line 1 in both files.

**session1.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

    // Set Global Session Variables from Form's POST Values
    $_SESSION["favcolor"] = $_POST['favcolor'];
    $_SESSION["favanimal"] = $_POST['favanimal'];
    
    // Go To Next Page
    $URL="session2.php";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$URL}';</script>";
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">';

}       
?>


<form action="" method="post">
Enter Color: <input type="text" name="favcolor" /><br />
Enter Animal: <input type="text" name="favanimal" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**session2.php**

```
<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["favanimal"] . ".";
?>
```

Comment: do a redirect in php instead of using javascript. Look up the PRG (post, redirect, get) pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Use PHP's `header('Location: /page-url');`
2. Render different content if `$_POST` is set

```php
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

    // Set Global Session Variables from Form's POST Values
    $_SESSION["favcolor"] = $_POST['favcolor'];
    $_SESSION["favanimal"] = $_POST['favanimal'];
    
    // Render other page content
    include "session2.php";
    
    // end the script to prevent loading this page contents
    die;
}       
?>


<form action="" method="post">
Enter Color: <input type="text" name="favcolor" /><br />
Enter Animal: <input type="text" name="favanimal" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

3. Submit form via an AJAX request and redirect depending on the response

Comment: For the AJAX request, I suggest doing a little research on this there's a lot of information on it out there

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I am looking to do something like you listed in option 1.  I had tried  header('Location: session2.php); but that resulted in => "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent."  Is a safe solution to use ob_start(); to buffer the output or is it better to stick with my JavaScript method with <META> tag backup?

Comment: @Mike Generally when receiving that error - it means there has already been some content generated. I'd suggest placing this at the top of the PHP file before any html content is generated - otherwise using the `ob_start();` and `ob_clean();` methods could help.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try this, but when I did it appears my SESSION variables were not set from the POST data submission.  There were no SESSION variables when I arrived at session2.php.

Comment: @Mike `session_start();` should only be called once, if you're including a file, you won't need to call it again. I'm not sure if this is happening to you, but I would check to make sure you're not calling `session_start();` in both files.

Comment: You are correct, I was calling session_start(); from both files.  Also am calling a session name in both files session_name('mydata);.  If I don't call session_start() in the second file, the SESSION variables do not come over.  Thanks for all the troubleshooting!